# Restrict bean creation count

Tags: spring

Is there a way to restrict the number of beans created in the application using Spring?.

I tried seeing ApplicationContextAware and BeansFactoryUtil. BeansFactoryUtils has a method called as countBeansIncludingAncestors() but that doesnt let me know if the bean is of particular type and so on.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Do you want to restrict the number of bean definitions or beans already created by a running context?

Comment: what i want is to restrict container to from creating bean defination more than the given count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to restrict the number of bean definitions. You could use an `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to check it

```
public class MaximumBeanDefinitionsPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private int maximum = 100;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        if (BeanFactoryUtils.countBeansIncludingAncestors(beanFactory) > this.maximum)
            throw new BeanDefinitionStoreException("Maximun number of bean defintions execeeded [" + maximum + "]");

    }
}
```